# If Condition is Not Working in JSTL

Tags: java, jstl

I am trying to set two variable using 2 if condition but it not working.
My code snippet is given below:

```
<c:forEach items="${user.roles}" var="role">    

        <span>Value : ${role.id }</span> **<!-- Print the value perfectly-->**

        <c:if test="${role.id  == 3}"> 
            <c:set var="admin" value="${role.id}"></c:set>  
            <span>Value : ${val }</span>
        </c:if>             

        <c:if test="${role.id  == 2}">   **<!-- But not work condition here -->**
            <c:set var="supporter" value="${role.id}"></c:set>  
                <span>Value : ${val }</span>                        
        </c:if>
</c:forEach>

<input type="checkbox" name="roles" value="3" ${admin ==3 ? 'checked' : ''}> Supporter
<input type="checkbox" name="roles" value="2" ${supporter ==2 ? 'checked' : ''}> Admin
```

Added tag Lib:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
```

Comment: you should not use `$` inside `{ }` ..replace `${$role.id  == }` with `${role.id == }`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<c:forEach items="${user.roles}" var="role">    

        <span>Value : ${role.id }</span> **<!-- Print the value perfectly-->**

        <c:if test="${rold.id  == 3}"> 
            <c:set var="admin" value="${role.id}"></c:set>  
            <span>Value : ${val }</span>
        </c:if>             

        <c:if test="${role.id  == 2}">   **<!-- But not work condition here -->**
            <c:set var="supporter" value="${role.id}"></c:set>  
                <span>Value : ${val }</span>                        
        </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Side note: comparisons will be evaluated within `${...}`. You don't need extra `$`

Comment: Thanks @lazyneuron, I have solved the problem using <c:choose>

`<c:forEach items="${user.roles}" var="role"> 
      <c:choose>
       <c:when test="${role.id  ==3}">
        <c:set var="admin" value="${role.id}"></c:set> 
       </c:when>
       <c:when test="${role.id  ==2}">
        <c:set var="supporter" value="${role.id}"></c:set> 
       </c:when>
      </c:choose>
     </c:forEach>
     
     <input type="checkbox" name="roles" value="3" ${admin ==3 ? 'checked' : ''}> Supporter
     <input type="checkbox" name="roles" value="2" ${supporter ==2 ? 'checked' : ''}> Admin`

Comment: Good to know! :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all,I guess this must be role.id instead of rold.id:

```
<c:if test="${$rold.id  == 3}">
```

Additionally, your role call must be with single '$' sign as follows:

```
test="${role.id == 3}"
```

or

```
test="${role.id eq 3}"
```

Here, you can find more information about this:
http://www.javatips.net/blog/jstl-check-equals-not-equals

Answer (score 1):

you use wrong syntax for if condition change this line

`<c:if test="${$rold.id  == 3}">` to  `<c:if test="${role.id  == 3}">`

I think its work for you